# Xamarin.Forms CollectionView trigger event on Focus/Hover

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I'm currently attempting to implement a Xamarin.Forms application which will be targeting Android TV. I have simplified my application to show the specific issue I'm having.

I have a collection of items which which I am displaying via a CollectionView. I am able to scroll around items inside this CollectionView using the D-Pad controls absolutely fine, as can be seen via this screenshot, where the "focussed"/"selected" item is visible if I make the layout bounds visible.
[image: Selected Item Visible]

There is nothing available except the "ItemSelected" event on the CollectionView which only occurs on actually pressing enter. I have tried to add in "Focus" events to all the elements that make up this page and nothing gets triggered. I am unsure what exactly is being "focussed" upon here.

This is my page:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Channels.ViewModels" 
             x:Class="Channels.MainPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:ChannelViewModel"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BackgroundColour}">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10">
        <Label Text="Selected Item" TextColor="White" Margin="0, 0, 10, 10"></Label>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="5"></LinearItemsLayout>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="5" Spacing="5" BackgroundColor="Red">
                        <Label Text="Test Text" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I would like to know exactly what is getting focus here and if it is possible to do something like I have stated.

I haven't found many examples of Xamarin being used in terms of Android TV so it might not be possible to do things like this. I have also tried implementing the same code in .NET Maui and cannot find any events that might work here.

Comment: hi, did you get solution for this? I am also looking for solution.

Comment: Sadly I didn't, this was just a side project so ended up just being shelved for now. I may raise a bug on GitHub and I will post back if get chance to but with Maui out, it might be low priority

Comment: ok. For now, we can use app like mousetoggle for android tv application https://github.com/virresh/matvt

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `GestureRecognizers` in the template to triger what you want to do when you selected the item or click on the item.

```
   <Label>
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't do anything until the item is tapped. In the question, the Android TV directional pad (d-pad) is being used to move from one item to the next (change focus). OP is asking how to detect when an item gains focus.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but what @ToolmakerSteve said is correct, sadly this won't do anything in the case of Android TV, there is no "tap" occurring
Doesn't look like any of the GestureRecognisers would be suitable either

Comment: @Jono_2007 Have you tru to use the `Focused` event of Label?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT - Yes, I have added `Focused="Label_Focused"` to that label above and breakpointed the event and no breakpoint is hit